# Perl File Writing and Reading using Hashes or Associative Arrays

Tags: perl, hash, associative-array

So I am working on this homework assignment and we have to read a text file of menu items in this case the text file reads -
Hamburgers - 1.79
Cheeseburgers - 2.00
Fries - 1.50
I need to be able to print out the text in the file and then take input to change the prices while putting them in an associative array or hash. I am honestly pretty suck at the moment here is what I have. I know about > means to write the file but I was not sure if it should be used since I want to view the original files first.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open(FH, "gp1data.txt") || die("Cannot open the file.");
print "$_";
while (<FH>){
    print "$_";
}
my %menu;
while (my $line2 = <$prices>) {
    chomp $line2;
    my @row = split(/-/, $line2);
    $menu{$row[0]} = $row[1];
}

<>;
```

What I am thinking is that the file gets opened and then prints whats in the file then I should be able to take what is printed and put it through the while loop while making it into a hash.

I wrote an associative array that contains what is in the text file to try using it in my code I have had no luck so far. here is the array I wrote.

```
%x = ("Hamburger" => 1.50, => "Cheeseburger" 2.00, "Fries" => 1.79);
$x[0] = "Hamburger 1.50";
$x[1] = "Cheeseburger 2.00";
$x[2] = "Fries 1.79";
for ($i=0; $i<3; $i++)
{
   $x[$i] =~ /-/;       
   $before = $`;          
   $after  = $';          
   $x{$before} = $after;  
}
foreach $item (keys %x)
{
    print "A $item costs \$$x{$item}\n"
}
<>;
```

What this does is it prints what comes before the "-" and after "-" so you can see what is being sold and how much. Below is the exact problem word for word I was given.

"write a Perl program that will allow the user to read some data from a file, and then give the user the option of modifying the price of an item, and then store the information back to a file that can be read again later. "

Comment: What is your specific question? It looks like you're struggling with the input, the output, and everything in between. Short of doing the entire assignment for you, how can I be of assistance?

Comment: "write a Perl program that will allow the user to read some data from a file, and then give the user the option of modifying the price of an item, and then store the information back to a file that can be read again later. "

Comment: Again, I'm not going to do the entire thing for you, so what, specifically, would you like help with?

Comment: my issue is that I feel I have the parts here but I am not putting them together properly, like how do I get the input after the file prints. I need inputs to change the list that was opened.

Comment: You would be able to use [Storable](https://metacpan.org/pod/Storable) which was first released with perl v5.7.3  You would need 'store' and 'retrieve'. There is an example using them at the top of the description.

Comment: I am not sure if my professor would let us do that, I have been working on it and I came up with a way to read the file turn the text in the file into a hash but I am having trouble making it so the user can change the hash from the file.

Comment: The code you posted won't even compile, so I'm still unsure what exactly you need help with. If you have some different, working code now, you should update your question with the changes.

Comment: For a start try adding `use strict;` and `use warnings;` to your code and fixing all of the problems they reveal.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I don't want to be mean. I remember the days I learned perl and saw a co-worker's script. He said *"It took me 1/2 an hour to write that single line, so it's ok if it takes you 1/2 an hour to read it."*.
Perl can be quite hard to read, so I kept the code simple.

Suppose this is your input file, say `menu.txt`:

```
Hamburgers - 1.79
Cheeseburgers - 2.00
Fries - 1.50
```

You can read it like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %menu;
open(my $input, "<menu.txt" ) || or die "cannot open menu.txt: $!\n";
while( my $line = <$input> ) {
    chomp($line);
    my ($item, $price) = split( / - /, $line );
    $menu{$item} = $price;
} 
close($input);
```

Now you have the hash `%menu` filled with the menu, 
i.e. `$menu{'Hamburgers'}` is `1.79` and so on.

How to change these values is left as an excercise. ;-)

After you have changed the values you can write them back to the (same or another) file:

```
open(my $output, ">new-menu.txt" ) || or die "cannot open new-menu.txt: $!\n";
foreach my $item ( keys %menu ) {
    print $output "$item - $menu{$item}\n";
} 
close($output);
```